# Strange ghost properties being sent to Proxy get method

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai, es6-proxy

This is the code that's causing the error:

```
console.log(objectWithProxyProperty);
```

the error that I am dealing with is either,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

or

```
Error: The assertion library used does not have a 'inspect' property or method.
```

depending on which checks I use, which is demostrated in the code below. What's clear is that the 'inspect' property is being sent to the get method, but 'inspect' is not a Symbol AND 'inspect' cannot be read with `prop in chaiAssert` either.

objectWithProxyProperty looks like:

```
  const objectWithProxyProperty = {};

  const assrt = <Partial<AssertStatic>>  function () {
    try {
      return chaiAssert.apply(chaiAssert, arguments);
    }
    catch (e) {
      return handleError(e);
    }
  };

  // the assert property on objectWithProxyProperty is a Proxy 
  objectWithProxyProperty.assert = new Proxy(assrt, {
    get: function (target, prop) {

      if (typeof prop === 'symbol') {
        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
      }

      if (!(prop in chaiAssert)) {
        return handleError(
          // new Error(`The assertion library used does not have property or method.`)
          new Error(`The assertion library used does not have a '${prop}' property or method.`)
        );
      }

      return function () {
        try {
          return chaiAssert[prop].apply(chaiAssert, arguments);
        }
        catch (e) {
          return handleError(e);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

What appears to be happening, is when I log this object with a proxy property called "assert", the proxy itself receives strange properties to the get method.

Specifically these properties are called 'inspect' and 'constructor', they do not seem to be Symbols.

So what I have to to "solve the problem" is add a check like so:

```
   const objectWithProxyProperty = {};

  const assrt = <Partial<AssertStatic>>  function () {
    try {
      return chaiAssert.apply(chaiAssert, arguments);
    }
    catch (e) {
      return handleError(e);
    }
  };

  let badProps =  {
     inspect: true,
     constructor: true
  };

  objectWithProxyProperty.assert = new Proxy(assrt, {
    get: function (target, prop) {

      if (typeof prop === 'symbol') {
        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
      }

      if (badProps[String(prop)]) {  // ! added this !
        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
      }

      if (!(prop in chaiAssert)) {
        return handleError(
          // new Error(`The assertion library used does not have property or method.`)
          new Error(`The assertion library used does not have a '${prop}' property or method.`)
        );
      }

      return function () {
        try {
          return chaiAssert[prop].apply(chaiAssert, arguments);
        }
        catch (e) {
          return handleError(e);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

What are these properties that do not exist on chaiAssert yet are not Symbols?

So far these ghost properties have been 'inspect' and 'constructor', but the reason I ask the question, is because I need to find out what other ones there might be, so that I can handle them ahead of time!

Comment: *"This is the code that's causing the error: `console.log(objectWithProxyProperty);`"* would not cause an error report of *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"*

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @NewToJS it might if you are using Proxy like I am

Comment: @guest271314 I am trying to figure out what other properties besides "inspect" and "constructor" will be sent to the get method of the Proxy...I'd like to know more exactly what's happening here..and if I figure out what's going on, then I know how to handle the properties that get sent to the Proxy's get method.

Comment: console.log() will inspect top level properties of the object, and print them if it's a simple object.

Comment: so the inspection will read the properties of the object and this will invoke the get method on the Proxy.

Comment: using Node.js, if I log this: `console.log({bear: 'chair', moose: {goose: 3}});`, it will read the top level properties.

Comment: Where is `chaiAssert` defined? What do you mean by "sent to the get method of the Proxy"?

Comment: @guest271314 what I mean is that the get method on the Proxy is called with "inspect" and "constructor" as the property argument, and (a) these are not symbols and (b) they don't seem to be available on the chaiAssert object - you can see the exact source here: https://github.com/sumanjs/suman/blob/master/lib/test-suite-helpers/t-proto-hook.ts#L48

Comment: the link above is good, but here is the permalink: https://github.com/sumanjs/suman/blob/7b6c7ab7ada1750f238ed94d3dc00fdc0a69396a/lib/test-suite-helpers/t-proto-hook.ts#L48

Comment: @AlexanderMills Have not tried `chai`. Can you reproduce issue at plnkr https://plnkr.co?

Comment: @guest271314 I can't get Plnkr to save the damn file, so I created a gist, you can copy to Plnkr manually, it works on Plnkr I just can't save it. When I hit the save button on Plnkr, I can see a 404 in the console. Lame.

Comment: but anyway here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/180f2219a13db2bfbc8ab304af06e817

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem in the browser, the problem only exists in Node.js. Here is the gist for Node.js: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/6b95f25e4b7fde1f93df6a8648d7a909

Comment: So Node.js: problem is replicable in the gist above. In the browser, problem does not seem to exist.

Comment: I filed an issue with Node on Github, we'll see what they say https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15703