# Proxies get trap is called with `inspect` (String!)

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I currently use proxies a lot but had a pitfall which I dont know how to solve without feeling hackish.

See this simple code:

```
var target = {bla: 4}
var handler = {
  get: function (target, name, receiver) {
    console.log(target, name)
  }
}

var p = new Proxy(target, handler)
console.log('Finished', p)
```

This outputs:

```
{ bla: 4 } Symbol(util.inspect.custom)
{ bla: 4 } 'inspect'
{ bla: 4 } 'inspect'
{ bla: 4 } Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
{ bla: 4 } Symbol(Symbol.iterator)
Finished: { bla: 4 }
```

In my real code I have no problems sorting out Symbols like `Symbol(util.inspect.custom)` because I can just relay them to `Reflect.get`. However, the getTrap is called with `'inspect'`, too. Twice! And thats a string - there is no difference between this "special" call and a normal access of a `target.inspect` property.

How can I solve this ambiguity? Why is the trap called with a non-symbol name anyway?

Comment: Its backwards compability, see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8071

Comment: Wow I even found that bug but obvisously didnt understant it well enough. I am wondering when they will drop that "backwards compatibility". Any answer why `'inspect'` is used twice?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498478/strange-ghost-properties-being-sent-to-proxy-get-method

Comment: Running the code in the question in Node.js v8, I don't get `inspect` twice. I get `Symbol(util.inspect.custom)`, then `'inspect'`, then `Symbol(Symbol.iterator)` and then your final `Finished` log. With Node.js v7 I get `'valueOf'` after `'inspect'` (and then `Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)` instead of `Symbol(Symbol.iterator)`) but otherwise the same.

Comment: I tried it with node v10.4.1 (on windows if this matters)